# WordPress woo commerce get products by brand

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product

In my **WordPress** project am trying to show `products list` based on `brand name`

This is my folder structure. Here am creating a API inside android folder.

[image]

In **android/brands_products.php** i want to show product list by brand name.

I tried this code:

```
<?php
require_once( '../wp-load.php' );
if ( woocommerce_product_loop() ) {

woocommerce_product_loop_start();

    if ( wc_get_loop_prop( 'total' ) ) {
        while ( have_posts() ) {
            the_post();

            /**
             * Hook: woocommerce_shop_loop.
             *
             * @hooked WC_Structured_Data::generate_product_data() - 10
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop' );

            wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
        }
    }

}
?>
```

But not working.

> example: Pbs is `brand name` want to select Pbs brand name products

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
require_once('../wp-load.php');   
global $woocommerce;
global $product;
$brand_product_args = array(
                'post_type' => 'product',
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'pwb-brand' => 'pbs',

                'order' => 'desc',
                'orderby' => 'date',
            );

            $brand_product_list = new WP_Query( $brand_product_args);

            while($brand_product_list->have_posts()) : $brand_product_list->the_post(); 
            $product_data = wc_get_product( $post->ID ); 

            endwhile; wp_reset_query();

            if(!empty($product_data))
            {
                $data['status']= true;
                $data['product']= $product_data;
            }
            else
            {
                $data['status']= false;
                $data['product']= array();
            }
    echo'<pre>'; print_r($data);exit;

    echo json_encode($data);
```

Answer (score 2):

Please use below code :

```
<?php
require_once('../wp-load.php');   
global $woocommerce;
global $product;
$brand_product_args = array(
                'post_type' => 'product',
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'product_cat' => 'pbs',
                'order' => 'desc',
                'orderby' => 'date'
            );

            $brand_product_list = new WP_Query( $brand_product_args);
            while($brand_product_list->have_posts()) : $brand_product_list->the_post(); 
            $product_data = wc_get_product( $post->ID ); 
            endwhile; wp_reset_query();
            if(!empty($product_list))
            {
                $data['status']= true;
                $data['product']= $product_data;
            }
            else
            {
                $data['status']= false;
                $data['product']= array();
            }
            echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Comment: Actually i get empty array and `$product_data` is empty

Comment: your brand `pbs` is category or what? could you please let me know?

Comment: I have updated the code right now please check it again

Comment: Please check now

Comment: No same empty array came

Comment: I have doubt how to connect products and brand, I mean in select query

Comment: Bro I got the answer please check my answer